# Closing Sessions in Spring Boot JMS CachingConnectionFactory

Tags: spring-boot, jms, spring-jms

I have my JMS configuration like below (**Spring boot 1.3.8**);

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableJms
    public class JmsConfig {

    @Autowired
    private AppProperties properties;

    @Bean
    TopicConnectionFactory topicConnectionFactory() throws JMSException {
        return new TopicConnectionFactory(properties.getBrokerURL(), properties.getBrokerUserName(),
                properties.getBrokerPassword());
    }

    @Bean
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws JMSException {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(topicConnectionFactory());
        connectionFactory.setSessionCacheSize(50);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() throws JMSException {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory());
        jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(Boolean.TRUE);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory defaultContainerFactory() throws JMSException {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        factory.setPubSubDomain(Boolean.TRUE);
        factory.setRecoveryInterval(30 * 1000L);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

This should work fine. But i am worried about whats written on the doc of [CachingConnectionFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/connection/CachingConnectionFactory.html)

Specially, these parts;

> NOTE: This ConnectionFactory requires explicit closing of all Sessions obtained from its shared Connection
>
> Note also that MessageConsumers obtained from a cached Session won't get closed until the Session will eventually be removed from the pool. This may lead to semantic side effects in some cases.

I thought the framework handled the closing session and connection part? If it does not; how should i close them properly?

or maybe i am missing something?

Any help is appreciated :)

**F.Y.I : I Use SonicMQ as the broker**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `JmsTemplate` will close the session; the javadocs refer to direct use outside of the framework.

Comment: What do you mean by direct use outside the framework ?

Comment: I mean that framework components (`JmsTemplate`, listener containers) will reliably close the sessions when appropriate. If you create your own sessions directly on the shared connection, you are responsible for closing them.